# UIScrollView-menu as navigation menu

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have an app where the menu bar is a UIScrollView consisting of UIButtons that I add on my UIViewController.
I want to change the UIViewController displayed when you press a button on the UIScrollView. 
But from the UIScrollView obviously I can't call :

```
[self.view presentViewController:myView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I would know what is the best way to handle this switch of views.

Comment: From what i understand, you have divided your screen into two areas. One is the scroll view that has the buttons for navigation and other is the area where you show some view depending on what button was pressed inside the scroll view?

Comment: Yes, in the lower level there is the view and over the view there is my ScrollView menu with buttons for choosing the view that I want to see...

Comment: Ok then you can add a container view in the area where you want to show some view and show the view controller using container views childviewcontroller property

Answer (score 0):

present it from the rootView of your app

```
[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window]rootViewController] presentViewController:<#your view#> animated:<#a bool#> completion:<#any handler#>];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    __weak UIViewController *viewCSelf=(UIViewController*)[self.superview nextResponder];

```
if([viewCSelf isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]){
```

[viewCSelf presentViewController:  animated:YES completion:nil];

}

Answer (score 0):

When there is a sideMenu based app, the base approach I have always seen is that, there has to a **ContainerViewController** that holds the menu & rest all other **viewControllers** are shown on the container in few of these ways -

- as a childViewController ([example here](https://github.com/simhanature/SHStripeMenu), [here](https://github.com/PlayAdz/PZSideMenuViewController), [here](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu), [here](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController))
- as a Push ([example here](https://github.com/balram3429/BTSimpleSideMenu))
- as a modal ([example here](https://github.com/balram3429/BTSimpleSideMenu))
- as a custom animated push or modal. ([example here](https://github.com/dasdom/DDHDynamicViewControllerTransitions))

Now you may have to rethink on the app design, how you want to proceed.

As mentioned above in push & model, you will have menu access only on the **ContainerViewController**. There is another way of doing it to add the ***"Menu as a Subview of the ApplicationWindow"***.

Hope this will help you to decide, which way you want to take.

Answer (score 0):

The most conventional way is to use `delegation`.
Anyways, your scrollView situated on view which has controller from which you can present another controller in any way want (present modal, push to navigation controller's stack, add as subview, etc.)
How to build your code depends on which object receives buttons actions. Lets suppose it's a view which contains scrollView with buttons:

```
// MenuBarView.h
@class MenuBarView;
@protocol MenuBarViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)menuBarView:(MenuBarView *)menuBar didSelectMenuItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end
@interface MenuBarView
@property (weak) id<MenuBarViewDelegate> delegate;
@end

// MenuBarView.m
...
- (void)menuButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
   [_delegate menuBarView:self
 didSelectMenuItemAtIndex:sender.tag] //you can use button's tag as row index
}
...
```

now adopt `MenuBarViewDelegate` protocol in viewController that owns MenuBarView instance and show sub view controllers depend on selected menu index

Comment: ok, I understand how to create the delegate method but I don't understand how to use in all my view controllers to switch between view controllers when I press the MenuBarView buttons...